# How to display rich text editor value?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new to *`JasperReports`*. In my database we saved the rich text editor value in particular column. That value contains raw html. I want to display this value in  *`JasperReports`*'s report without markup language for that i have set the properties 'markup' as html. But in that output the table and header didn't come as actual format.